# QueryDSL how do I create a SubQuery with its own joins?

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I am trying to build a subquery for a QueryDSL select that uses an **exists** clause in a BooleanExpression.

The data model is such that there are projects which contain a single media. Media can have many dimensions. I am looking to select projects that have certain dimensional data and am using a subquery to accomplish that.

The subquery looks like this:

```
QProject project = QProject.project;
QMedia media = QMedia.media;

Predicate subExpression = JPAExpressions.selectOne()
            .from(media)
            .innerJoin(media.dimensions)
            .where(project.media.id.eq(media.id),
                dimension.dimensionType.id.eq(Long.valueOf(inputDimensionType))).exists();
```

I store this as a predicate but, when I try to utilize it inside of a parent query I get an error: `antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: elements`

The generated portion that is causing the error looks something like this (from the hibernate.hql.internal logs):

```
... and ((exists (select 1
from com.app.model.Media media
  inner join elements(media.dimensions)
```

That is the error that happens when I plug it into a master query like this:

```
JPAQuery<ResponseCurve> query = new JPAQuery<>(this.entityManager);
query.select().from(project)
  .where(project.state.eq(inputState))
  .where(subExpression);
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer as I misunderstood what the subquery was doing, my bad. Out of curiosity, what happens if you have `QDimension dimension = QDimension.dimension` and call `.innerJoin(media.dimensions, dimension)` rather than the `.innerJoin(media.dimensions)` that's currently there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible issues with this query:

1. You're trying to reference alias `dimensions`, but you never associated it with the join to `media.dimensions`
2. You're dereferencing `dimension.dimensionType` without a join. For identifier values this is possible, for any other property, it is not.

What about:

```
QProject project = QProject.project;
QMedia media = QMedia.media;
QDimension dimension = QDimension.dimension;

Predicate subExpression = JPAExpressions.selectOne()
        .from(project.media, media)
        .innerJoin(media.dimensions, dimension )
        .on(dimension.dimensionType.id.eq(Long.valueOf(inputDimensionType))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot assign `JPAExpressions` to a `Predicate` object, it seems to generate `JPQLQuery<Tuple>`. Do you know why?

Comment: I copied it from your original query, but it seems I am missing the “exists()” call at the end.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am not OP though just to be clear.